# access selectcommand using codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, select

How can I change my selecommand, and keep it through the remainder of the page (when using pagination, sorting)?

I have a page of checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_3" />
<asp:Button runat="server" Id="CustomButton" text="Create Report" PostBackUrl="report.aspx?"/>
```

Then on report.aspx I want to generate a standard listview based on the selections in the checkbox.

```
 <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ReportListView" DataSourceID="ReportListViewSDS">
  <LayoutTemplate runat="server">
       ...<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />...
  </LayoutTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
     ...
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I want to be able to sort and paginate that listview.  This is an idea of what i want in the code behind:

```
Protected Sub ReportListView_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

     ' What's the correct way to reference the listview?  
     ' When I use the below code i get "ReportListView is not declared...."

     ' ReportListView.SqlCommand = "SELECT " & checkbox1 & ", " & checkbox2 & " WHERE..."

End Sub
```

I'm not sure if I'm even going in the right direction with this, any help is appreciated.  Will the changes i make to the sql command in the PreRender function hold when I have applied pagination or sorting to the listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was much easier than I thought.  Sorry, just a newbie mistake i guess.  i ended up simply doing:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim SqlCommand As String
    ' create the sql command using the Request.Form vars i wanted.
    ' ...
    ' Run the sql command, I can access the listview directly, just like a global variable:
    ReportListView.SelectCommand = SqlCommand
    ReportListView.DataBind()
 End Sub
```

And that seemed to do it.  Actually very easy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to open a new page and use the prior page's values in the select statement for the `ListView`'s `SqlDataSource` on the new page, correct?

First, a few observations:

1. In your first page, you appear to be intending to call the second page with a query string (`PostBackUrl="report.aspx?`), but you don't appear to set the query string.
2. Your `PreRender` event for the `ListView` control has the wrong signature.  It only takes one argument, `EventArgs`:

   Protected Sub ReportListView_PreRender(ByVal e As EventArgs)
3. Your `ListView` appears to be using a `SqlDataSource` as it's binding source (`DataSource="ReportListViewSDS"`).  More about that below.
4. There is no `SqlCommand` property or method for the `ListView` control.

Since you're binding the `ListView` to a `SqlDataSource`, it'd be simplest to set the Select command and the parameters in the markup, like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ReportListViewSDS" runat="server"
     SelectCommand="SELECT checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3 FROM <table> WHERE checkbox1 = @parm1 AND checkbox2 = @parm2 AND checkbox3 = @parm3">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="checkbox_1" Name="parm1" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="checkbox_2" Name="parm2" />
        <asp:FormParameter FormField="checkbox_3" Name="parm3" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Replace `<table>` in the `SelectCommand` with the name of your table.  You can adjust the names of the columns you're selecting, as well as the parameters you're using, as desired.  I simply used 3 checkboxes as that's what you had in the code you posted.

Also note, **NO VALIDATION** of the parameters will be done by the `SqlDataSource`, so if you want to prevent SQL Injection attacks and other security risks, you'll want to do validation in the `Selecting` event of the `SqlDataSource`.

More information can be found here:

[SqlDataSource Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx)

[FormParameter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formparameter.aspx)

Comment: SOrry, my question was not really clear.  I'm familiar with the standard list view, and using the Select command and the parameters like you have mentioned.  But my goal was that the select query would have entries from Request.From (ie. the previous pages checkboxes).  I found I was making it much more difficult.  See the solution below.